# Proof explanation: If $p$ is prime, then $x^2 \equiv 1 \:(\mathrm{mod}\:p) \Leftrightarrow x \equiv \pm1 \:(\mathrm{mod}\:p)$

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I was asked to prove the following theorem:

> Let $p$ be prime. Then for any $x$, the following holds true: $x^2
> \equiv 1 \:(\mathrm{mod}\:p) \Leftrightarrow x \equiv \pm 1
> \:(\mathrm{mod}\:p)$

My proof is as follows:

$\begin{alignat}{2} && x^2 \equiv 1 \:(\mathrm{mod}\:p) \\ &\Leftrightarrow\quad &x^2 -1\equiv 0 \:(\mathrm{mod}\:p) \\ &\Leftrightarrow &p \mid (x^2 - 1) 
\\ &\Leftrightarrow &p \mid (x - 1)(x + 1) 
\\ &\Leftrightarrow &p \mid (x - 1) \vee p \mid(x + 1)
\\ &\Leftrightarrow &x \equiv 1 \:(\mathrm{mod}\:p)\vee x\equiv -1 \:(\mathrm{mod}\:p) \end{alignat}$

**My problem:** I didn't (actively) use the fact that $p$ is prime, which is suspicious to me, because it means that either my proof is wrong, or that I used it somewhere in an implicit way without realizing it.

Can somebody point out where I used the fact that $p$ is prime?

Comment: You did use that $p$ is prime, the equivalence between the third line from the bottom and the penultimate line needs that. (For composite moduli, in general only the implication from the penultimate line to the one above holds.)

Comment: You use that $p$ is prime  when you use *Euclid's lemma*.

Comment: Yes you do it! When you say that $p|(x-1)(x+1) \implies p|(x-1)$ or $p|(x+1)$. If $p$ is not a prime number this fact is false, example $8|(3+1).(3-1)$ but $8$ doesn't divides $(3+1)$ or $(3-1)$

Comment: Actually, $p$ prime is only used in the "only if" part.

Comment: Thank you all very much, I understood it! I completely forgot about euclid's lemma.

Comment: Another argument would use that $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$ is a field when $p$ is prime, and an equation of degree $n$ in a field cannot have more that $n$ roots.

Comment: another argument is that an alternate $\sqrt{1}$ exists. for example 3 in mod 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The step
$$p \mid (x-1)(x+1) \iff p\mid (x-1) \lor p\mid (x+1)\tag{$\ast$}$$
uses that $p$ is prime.

Actually not quite, because the equivalence $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{m} \iff x \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{m}$ also holds for some composite moduli (and it trivially holds for $\lvert m\rvert \leqslant 1$). It holds whenever the group of units modulo $m$ is cyclic, and for composite $m > 1$ that happens when $m = 4$, $m = p^k$, or $m = 2p^k$ for an odd prime $p$ and $k \geqslant 1$.

So the specific case $(\ast)$ of
$$p \mid ab \iff p\mid a \lor p \mid b$$
does not characterise primes (or units or $0$) like the general case does.

Answer (score -1):

For $p\ge2$, We have either $p|x-1$ or $p|x+1$.
So $x+1 \equiv 0 \mod p$ or $x-1 \equiv 0 \mod p$.
Implying
$$x\equiv \pm 1 \mod p$$